# json массив не передается через post запрос

Tags: json, windows, cmd, httpie

Импортировал из httpie post запрос который правильно отработал, в bat скрипт.

```
http --form POST 'https://example.com/add'  'Json={"AddHost":[{"To_host":"723"}],"From_host":"233"}'
```

Отображается ошибка:

```
http: error: gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed
Couldn’t resolve the given hostname. Please check the URL and try again.
```

Comment: При чём тут json если вам английским языком написано что домен не наден?

Comment: @AlexeyTen Ten
Как раз это мне и надо понять почему  не найден. Возможно проблема в синтаксисе запроса

Comment: У вас не найден домен `example.com`.  Ищите опечатку или проблему в настройках сети.